# Storing multiple strings in nested structure

Tags: c++, c, c++11, struct

I have 2 structures named `Phone` and `Patient`, respectively:

```
struct Phone{
    char description[4];
    char number[10];
};

struct Patient{
    int id;
    char name[15];
    struct Phone phone;
};
```

Now, on creating a patient's array like:

```
struct Patient patient = [
    {1024, "Shaggy Yanson", {"CELL","3048005191"} },
]
```

Upon printing the phone description value, I get the output as `CELL3048005191`.

**NOTE: I cannot change the array**

I want to know what is causing the problem. Is it the structure definition?

Comment: c and c++ are different languages. Please pick one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. The problem is that C-style strings require one extra character to store a *nul terminator*. This is the character `'\0'` which is placed at the end of every C-style string. So, to store a string like `"CELL"` requires an array of size 5, not 4.

Of course, you can still store the 4 characters `'C'`, `'E'`, `'L'` `'L'` in an array of size 4. It's just that, then it's no longer a C-style string, because it no longer has a nul terminator. If this is what you want to do, then you will have to take special measures when you process the data (like, when you print it, for example).

Comment: hey john, thanks for your answer. May I know what should I do in order to correct this thing. As the length of the string is already defined using a macro and the display function is also already defined, which just directly prints the phone.description like printf(phone.description);

Comment: @ManrajSingh If that is how your code is, then your code has a bug. There's no way to fix the bug without changing the code.

Comment: @ManrajSingh `printf(phone.description);` requires a nul terminator (it also has *undefined behavior* if the string contains any `%` character). To print a string that has no nul terminator, you can specify a max length in the `%s` specifier of `printf()`, ie `printf("%.4s", phone.description); printf("%.10s", phone.number);` or, if the lengths are in macros: `printf("%.*s", (int)desc_length_here, phone.description); printf("%.*s", (int)number_length_here, phone.number);`